# Application stopped to find shared library

Tags: linux, debian, bash, libraries, wkhtmltopdf

wkhtmltopdf is used to create pdf files in Debian Linux.

wkhtmltopdf suddenly stopped working. Running it from shell throws library not found error:

```
root@x:/usr/local/bin# ./wkhtmltopdf
./wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Symlink of library exists in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu :

```
root@x:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls -l libQt5Core.so.5* 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 jaan  30  2020 libQt5Core.so.5 ->
 libQt5Core.so.5.11.3 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 jaan  30  2020
libQt5Core.so.5.11 -> libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5200168 jaan  30  2020 libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
```

How to allow wkhtmltopdf to find library in Debian Linux ?

I tried to copy library to the same directory where whhtmltopdf exists (/usr/local/bin ) but problem persists.
It has worked for years but suddenly stopped working. Debian VPS server was re-booted unexpectedly, maybe this caused it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your system..

if it does not help ; try ( as root or sudo it yourself )

```
strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so
```

source : https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4497

You should backup the file before alter it.